# Investigate the convergence of a series with non-negative terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Investigate the convergence of a series with non-negative terms $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{\sqrt{n 2^n}}.$$

I think we can use the Stirling approximation? but i dont no how to use it in this promblem.

Comment: Write $$(2n-1)!! =\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$Can you apply Stirling's Formula now?

Comment: With mostly multiplications this problem can be solved by studying the successive quotients of the terms of the series $a_{n+1}/a_n=(2n+1)\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}2^{-1/2}$. This is large for $n$ large. So, $a_n$ cannot be tending to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the help